# How to apply a mixed effect model to my dataset

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, mixed

I have a large dataset but for this analysis I am focusing on three columns that includes (a) the concentration of hormone X (ug/g), (b) body mass (kg) and gender (male/female).

I am just wondering how best to approach the analysis and I thought a mixed effect model was most appropriate. That is, the concentration of hormone X increases with body mass however it is also dependent on gender.

I tried using this code:

```
model2=lme(conc.hormone~gender*Body.Mass..kg.,
data=epidemiologythesisdata,
 na.omit = TRUE)
```

...however I received an error. Is there a way that I can graph the relationship between hormone concentration and body mass with two different lines for gender?

Thanks

Comment: A few points here. Firstly, this is a stats question rather than a programming question. and should probably be asked over at the stats stackexchange site Crossvalidated. However, it seems pretty clear that you don't have any random effects here (unless you have repeated measures on the same individuals), since you are interested in both gender and weight as explanatory variables / fixed effects. The answer to your last question is "yes", but without seeing a sample of data and perhaps the code you have tried so far, it will be difficult to help you with this.

Comment: In addition to @AllanCameron's question: can you explain *why* you thought a mixed effect model was appropriate?  (The fact that you want to model the effect of more than one independent (predictor) variable {body mass, gender} on the dependent (response) variable {hormone} does not itself imply a mixed model ...)

Comment: and .. .what error did you get? can we have a [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.